# How to choose between pooled ols and fixed/random effect

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

I have unbalanced panel dataset, large N and relatively small T (about 15 timesteps). I know that the ols completely disregards the panel structure of the data. I was wondering if there is a test that allows me to empirically say that fixed/random effect model is empirically better than pooled OLS, the same way we use the Hausman test to decide between fixed and random effect.

Comment: I'm not clear on why you need a test.  Usually it's best to spend time in model specification that captures the essence of the data generating process.

Comment: Typically, one tests the FE vs. pooling specification with a Wald test to see whether adding the FEs seems beneficial.

Comment: You mean the Wald test that is automatically done at the bottom of the xtreg ____, fe on Stata ?

Comment: I do not know about Stata but its documentation will tell you. Or any textbook about panel models.